# Access-VBA Fetch corresponding records from one table write to another table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a newbie to Access and i'm trying to build a form to be used in the place where i work.

I have a mainform which has comboboxes as below.

Department: [MainDepartment] Possible values (Welding, painting, etc..)

Shift: [MainShift] Possible values (1, 2, 3)

Date: [MainDate]

My mainform has also have a unique ID field[ID] and linked to tblReportPersonnel.

tblPersonnel

```
PerID   NameSurname Department  Week1   Week2   Week3   ... Week52

123     John Doe    Welding     1       2           3       2

456     James Rod   Painting    2       3           1       1
```

When the user selects date, shift and department i want to run a vba code to lookup matching values from tblPersonnel and write the corresponding values to tblReportPersonnel with mainforms id.

This vba code needs to convert date to weeknumber and use it as column name.
I will trigger VBA code with AfterUpdate event of one of the mainform fields.
The table structure of tblReportPersonnel is below.

tblReportPersonnel

```
ID  PerID

785 123

785 872

785 578
```

```
Private Sub fetch()
Dim varWeek As String
varWeek = Format([Forms]![Mainform]![MainDate] - 1, "ww")
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT tblPersonnel.[PerID]"
From Personel
WHERE (((Personel.varWeek)=[Forms]![MainForm]![MainShift] And ((tblPersonnel.Department)=[Forms]![MainForm]![MainDepartment));
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: reconsider what you are doing in your personnel table, Do a quick search on normalization.  any time you see a table with fields like "week1", "week2","week3"....  it's usually an indication of an improperly designed table structure.  What you are trying to accomplish would be simpler with a table structure such as EmployeeID (FK), WeekNum, WeekValue.  On your form you already know the employeeID, then just calculate the weekNum, and run a query to find the corresponding value.

Comment: i am entering which shift an employee will work for 52 weeks.

Comment: I got that, just saying the table is designed improperly.  You're making this a lot harder on yourself then you have too. Set the table up properly and it becomes much simpler.

Comment: the personnel table is going to be filled by team leaders who are not so familiar with computer. i will make them fill the table in datasheet view for their department. this way it will be user-friendly.

Comment: If you're insistent upon this format, perhaps you want to use excel and not Access, Excel is better suited to how you are trying to do this. However in a properly designed database it should be no problem. I'm afraid if your not willing to change your table design or input methods then you are in for a very hard road ahead of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all WHO pushed me to find my own answer.

```
Private Sub Answer()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim hafta As Integer
hafta = Format([Forms]![Ana]![Text4] - 1, "ww")
Debug.Print hafta

strSQL = "SELECT [Personel].[Sicil no] FROM [Personel] WHERE [Personel].[" & hafta & "] = " & [Forms]![Ana]![Combo25] & " And [Personel].[Bölüm] = '" & [Forms]![Ana]![Combo23] & "'"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
With rs
 If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
  .MoveLast
  .MoveFirst
While (Not .EOF)
     Debug.Print rs![Sicil no]
     'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
     DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [RaporPersonel] ([ID], [Sicil no]) VALUES ('" & [Forms]![Ana]![Text0] & "' , " & rs![Sicil no] & ")"
 'DoCmd.SetWarnings True

     .MoveNext
Wend
End If
.Close
End With
ExitSub:
Set rs = Nothing

 Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

I didn't translate the field names to English this time.
But it will be helpful for the people searching for the same answer.

This code;

+Converts date to weeknumber from the main form.

+Then goes to personnel table and checks if there is a matching record depending on two checkboxes on mainform and date.

+It then writes the results to another table called ReportPersonnel with the unique ID of the main form.

Afterwards i will enhance the code more. I will make a continuous subform on the mainform and requery the subform just after the code.

The reason i created this code is;

When user selects his own department, the date and the shift from the main form,
the list will be populated in the continuous form automatically. That's why the user doesnt have to select 40 personnel in a shift manually.

and user is going to enter more details about that personnel.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You will find writing a database with the tblPersonnel having all those week columns will result in you writing a lot of complex code.

Your tblPersonnel has a lot of columns and is in what I refer to as "Wide Format".

When you use databases you need to normalise your data and you end up with a list of data that is very long ("Long Format").

The most important things to appreciate are:

1. users like to work with wide data as it helps them do data entry and view data BUT
2. databases need to store their data as long data to work well.
3. More importantly, getting a database to convert long data and display it as wide data then allow users to edit it, is a nightmare.  DO NOT GO THERE!

I created a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kT3WnyYjULk  which discusses using long and wide format data in excel and demos the benefits of each.

Some of what it presents may be of use to you (and it demos PowerQuery which is worth knowing about).

To re-iterate what Gene said, I think given your experience with VBA and Access you should use Excel to meet you users requirements.  (However, note that you can always use powerquery to convert and move the data from wide format into a long format should you need to later use it in a database - and it's easier to work like this).